# Unable to change color of keywords within a text area

Tags: javascript, css

I am attempting to write a program that can detect if you inserted a JavaScript keyword, and if you have, it will change the color of it so it will stand out(It will eventually submit the code and I will use it for offline debugging on a chromebook).  However, it seems that I cannot change the color of the text within the textfield when it matches a keyword. [**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/szrsh77L/)

Here is the code: 
 
CSS:

```
#JScodeinputbox{font-family:Arial;}
#JScodeoutputbox{}
.JSfunctions{color:blue;}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<textarea id="JScodeinputbox" wrap="logical" rows="30" cols="70" onkeyup="checkHighlight();"></textarea>
<canvas>
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var codeInput = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
var keywords = new Array("var", "if");
function checkHighlight(){
    var codeInput1 = codeInput[0].value;
    if(codeInput1 === keywords[0]){
        keywords[0].indexOf(codeInput1).className = "JSfunctions";
    }
}
```

If anyone know how to resolve this issue or simpler alternatives(preferrably not involving JQuery, PHP, etc.) it would be much appreciated. 
PS: I know it is not about it being onkeyup, I have that for a reason.  It also works when I run other methods, so I don't think it's formatting, either(but it could be).

Comment: This won't work with standard textareas. You need something like [ace](http://ace.c9.io/).

Comment: I'll look into it.  Seems like what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JQuery Highlight Textarea](http://mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/) plugin with this code (sample from site)

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="5">...</textarea>

<script>
  $('textarea').highlightTextarea({
    words: ['Lorem ipsum', 'vulputate']
  });
</script>
```

and problem solved

Comment: Wow!  Thanks!  I didn't expect it to be that simple!

Comment: The code does not highlight text in a `textarea` element. Instead, it generates a different element, looking like a textarea, with some markup inside it. So the answer to the question is really “you can’t” (since `textarea` does not allow any inner markup), possibly with the annotation “but you can use elements other than `textarea`”.